# Como faço para centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente em css?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Calculo de idade

```
    body{
        text-align: center;
        justify-items: center;
    }

</style>

<h1>Calcular idade a partir da data de nascimento</h1>
<h3>Digite a sua data de nascimento para que seja calculada sua idade</h3>

    <input type="date" name="nascimento" id="ano de nascimento"> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Clique para ver sua idade">

        wasd   <!--tentei centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente este wasd como exemplo, porem não consegui-->
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seja bem vindo ao SOPt!
Recomendo pesquisar alguns tópicos antes de postar uma pergunta, pois aqui mesmo já existem diversas respostas para sua dúvida.

Em tempo, observe a seguir um exemplo completo criado com sintaxe HTML5:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
   <h1>Calcular idade a partir da data de nascimento</h1>
   <h3>Digite a sua data de nascimento para que seja calculada sua idade</h3>
       <input type="date" name="nascimento" id="ano de nascimento"> <br>
       <input type="button" value="Clique para ver sua idade">
       <p>wasd</p> 
</section>
</body>
</html>
```